# namespace included xml - direct xpath expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is there a way in xsl 1.0 to mention the xpath expression as below, to get the value of node "a"

```
/Root/a - doesnt work
```

instead of

```
/Root/*[local-name() = 'a'] - this will work
```

This is my xml file

```
<Root xmlns:ns="http://abc">
  <ns:a>value</ns:a>
</Root>
```

The reason am asking, in my xslt, in many lines, we specified the xpath expression as `/Root/a` (or other nodes), because the xml file did not have any namespaces before. However the xml file has namespaces now, we have to change everywhere, with `*[local - name()]`. Instead of that, is there a way to change my xsl, in one place, so that the earlier xpath expressions also work, even with namespace included xml?

Comment: If your renamed `/Root/a` to `/Root/b`, how can you change your xsl in one place so that the earlier xpath expressions also work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, you can declare `xpath-default-namespace`. In XSLT 1.0 is better to  declare namespace prefix and use it in XPath expressions, than use `local-name()` function e.g.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://abc"/>
```

In XPath:

```
/Root/ns:a
```